# React - Display Div when click

Tags: reactjs

I would like to show a component when i'm clicking to another one. I set a value "showPanelInfo" to false at the beginning and when I click to the "CharacterCard" component, I tried to change value of setShowPanelInfo to true but it's not working.

```
import React from "react";
import { useQuery, gql } from "@apollo/client";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { QueryResult } from "../components";
import CharacterCard from "../containers/characters/character-card";
import CharacterPanelCard from "../components/characters/character-panel-card";
import CreatePlanetModal from "../components/characters/create-character-modal";

const Characters = () => {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_CHARACTERS);


  // SHOW HIDE PLANET PANEL

  const [showPanelInfo, setShowPanelInfo] = React.useState(false);
  const displayPanelInfo = () => setShowPanelInfo(true);
  const hidePanelInfo = () => setShowPanelInfo(false);


  // CREATE ID IN STATE - DEFAULT 1
  const [characterId, setCharacterId] = React.useState(1);

  return (
    <PageContainer>
      <ResultContainer>
        <QueryResult error={error} loading={loading} data={data}>
          {/* Grid of characters */}
          {data?.characters?.map((character) => (
            <CharacterCard
              key={`${character.id}`}
              character={character}
              onClick={() => {
                displayPanelInfo();
                setCharacterId(character.id);
              }}
            />
          ))}
        </QueryResult>


      {/* Panel Container */}
      {showPanelInfo ? (
        <CharacterPanelCard characterId={characterId} />
      ) : null}

    </PageContainer>
  );
};

export default Characters;
```

Any Ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Code looks alright imo, although you could just use `setShowPanelInfo` to show/hide and not have the other two redundant functions. Maybe, some CSS is affecting your component? What happens if you remove the always show `<CharacterPanelCard />

Comment: Include your code

Comment: I updated my question with the code (i had to remove some lines otherwise i couldn't edit the post

Comment: @LoXatoR: Sorry i didn't get what you are asking me to do! I also just used the setShowPanelInfo directly inside the onClick but it's still not work :/

Comment: I mean what happens if you remove the conditional rendering, and always show `<CharacterPanelCard />` ?

Comment: if i just write this:
      {/* Panel Container */}
      <CharacterPanelCard characterId={characterId} />

it shows the panel card

Comment: I think it's not even detecting the click but i don't know why :/